# Is possible to create ACAccount with just login and password?

Tags: macos, twitter, accounts, acaccount

In my application (for Mac OS), I need to login to Twitter and check for new posts directly with login and password, which user will specify in my application.

Is it possible to do it with Accounts framework?

Maybe, somebody can show some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter API does not allow you to connect to a user account with username and password.  This is called "Basic Auth" and it was removed by Twitter in June of 2010.

Twitter now requires developers to implement a system called "OAuth" in order to securely access Twitter accounts.  This is more secure for users than Basic Auth because it means that users never have to hand over their user credentials to a third-party application.

OAuth can be daunting for new developers, and I strongly recommend that you look into libraries written by other developers who have already implemented OAuth so that you don't have to.

If you look at Twitter's [Open Source Examples Page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/open-source-examples) you will see many such libraries in a variety of different languages and platforms.

Good luck!